# Increasing Amazon Linux 2 AMI /tmp size

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I'm trying to install tensorflow on a Amazon linux AMI EC2 micro instance, but I keep getting `EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device` even while the disk is empty.
On ubuntu server, I fix this increasing the /tmp size with the command `sudo mount -o remount,size=4G,noatime /tmp`, however this command fails on Amazon Linux telling me that /tmp is not mounted at all.
How can I increase /tmp size on Amazon Linux 2?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following can help in achieving the tmp space.

```
cd                              # change to your home directory    
fallocate -l 20G mydrive.img    # create the virtual drive file
mkfs -t ext3 mydrive.img        # format the virtual drive
sudo umount /tmp                # unmount the /tmp
sudo mount -t auto -o loop mydrive.img /tmp   # mount the virtual drive
```

Comment: This results in an error - `TMPDIR=/tmp is set to a non-accessible location`. You must additionally apply permissions to the new `/tmp` drive - `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` (This gives `drwxrwxrwt.`, which is what I originally had for `/tmp`).